# Spring security and login using google

Tags: spring-security, openid, google-apps

I implemented in my web application spring security login using google open id as it is described in the [article](http://krams915.blogspot.se/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html)

But is there a way to allow login for all members of some google apps domain, w/o listing explicitly all users?

Or, at least, keep users list, but make ids host-independent (now google generates different ids for each host of deployment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this by whitelisting the corresponding domains:

- implement AuthenticationUserDetailsService<OpenIDAuthenticationToken>
- override loadUserDetails() and check for the domain

You can view the exact code on GitHub ([Sample Code](https://github.com/techdev-solutions/trackr-backend/blob/b139506f217ede00cac6861956d45912d448e854/src/main/java/de/techdev/trackr/domain/employee/login/TrackrUserDetailsService.java#L74)) or read about how we implemented Spring & OAuth here: https://techdev.io/en/developer-blog/using-spring-and-oauth-in-trackr